# Could not determine current country code: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -2.)"

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am getting this error code when using 'MKMapView' on the iPhone 4:

```
Could not determine current country code: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -2.)"
```

The map loads fine with coordinates etc, but this gets logged.

Any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: Are you checking in Simulator? It seems the Map doesn't have valid coordinates.. do you have your userlocation property for Map enabled? If yes you have to simulate location for simulator..

Comment: Im testing it on a device, the iPhone 4, not simulator. The map loads fine with coordinates etc, but this gets logged.

Comment: It seems bug in iOS, which version of iOS are you using ?

Comment: iOS7.1.1, the bug only started to show today, and i didnt change any code. strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this today on my iPad4-Wifi.
Reading more of the message, it stated that it had o internet connection.
Sure enough, the iPad lost connection to the wifi for some reason.

I reselected our wifi network, retried the test and it worked.